# paintComponent not changing shape

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, jcomponent

can someone take a look at my code below and tell me why, when I change the following two statements, I do not see a change on the rectangle that is painted. So if I change:

```
g.setColor(Color.black); 
g.fillRect(l, w, 100, 100);
```

The program still prints a black rectangle with the same dimensions and in the same position that I first started with even though I change color to yellow or try to change the dimensions or location. I am BlueJ. The following is my full code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingPaintDemo2 extends JComponent {

public static boolean isWall = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI(); 
        }
    });
}


private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
    //SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
    JPanel MyPanel = new JPanel();
     MyPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000));
     MyPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 200));
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    f.add(new MyPanel());
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);

}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    int l = 10;
    int w = 10;

  g.setColor(Color.black); 
  g.fillRect(l, w, 100, 100);

        }

}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your SSCCE doesnt compile where is `MyPanel` class or did you mean `new SwingPaintDemo2()`?

On the assumption you meant `new SwingPaintDemo2()`:

The code does work just fine but the `JFrame` is sized very small:

[image]

because you dont give it any size and none of its components have a size as they do not have any components added to them, thus we must make the `JComponent` return a correct size so when we call pack() our `JFrame` is sized correctly

**Solution**

override `getPreferredSize()` of `JComponent` to return a width and height which fits all drawings.

Some suggestions though:

- Dont extend `JComponent` rather extend `JPanel`

Here is an example (your code with above fixes implemented):

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingPaintDemo2 extends JPanel {

    public static boolean isWall = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
        //SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
        JPanel MyPanel = new JPanel();
        MyPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000));
        MyPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 200));
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new SwingPaintDemo2());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int l = 10;
        int w = 10;

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(l, w, 100, 100);

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(150, 150);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, that did it. The funny thing is that the code that I first posted was not giving me a compile error, maybe the class got corrupted because I was moving things around? but when I created a new class with the same code I saw the compile error. But regardless, Thanks for taking the time to help me out. If I could have upvote you I would have (still working on my reputation - newbie).

Comment: @user1894469 atleast its working now. And thats not a problem, dont forget to check the tick mark next to the post if its the answer.

Comment: I was just about to ask you about that :) thks again.